# Calculating separated shapes area in a binary mask with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to detect human body mask, but my algorithm sometimes makes mistake like the image below. I was thinking if I could calculate individual shapes area (connected white pixels) in the image, I can just keep the largest one and my problem will be solved. Is there a way for that?

[image]

Comment: use `connectedComponentsWithStats` instead of that answer down below. it will give you [the area in pixels](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gac7099124c0390051c6970a987e7dc5c5) and in general you should work through the tutorials found in the official documentation. that's how you learn about the tools you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use cv2.findContours() to get the outlines of each of the white blobs. The contours come with a lot of extra properties that you can find here:

https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/d32/tutorial_py_contour_properties.html

This includes getting their internal area.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread("outline.png");

# set as binary mask
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
mask = cv2.inRange(gray, 155, 255);

# contours # if you're using OpenCV 3* then it returns as _, contours, _
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

# find the biggest contour
biggest = None;
biggest_area = -1;
for con in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(con);
    if biggest_area < area:
        biggest_area = area;
        biggest = con;

# draw the new contour
redraw = np.zeros_like(img);
cv2.drawContours(redraw, [biggest], -1, (100, 150, 0), -1);

# show
cv2.imshow("Biggest", redraw);
cv2.waitKey(0);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the connectedComponents function in OpenCV for this purpose.

```
retval, labels=cv.connectedComponents(image[, labels[, connectivity[, ltype]]])
```

More details of this function can be found in the documentation. The output image is a labelled image where each connected component is given a label.
The output retval is the total number of labels (also number of connected components).

Then all you have to do is to iterate through the connected components to find the one with most pixels.